# Data from HIve to elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, hive

I have cretaed a table and inserted values..
For inserting data to Elastic search I created external hive table.

data is not inserting to external table...

Getting error:

```
Error during job, obtaining debugging information...
Execution failed with exit status: 2
Obtaining error information

Task failed!
Task ID:
 Stage-0

Logs:

/tmp/hadoop/hive.log
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
```

Comment: Please help me... Thanks in advance

Comment: please show us how you are trying ,may be some code and also share the complete log.